# Unsupervised transformation with Random Trees

Tags: random-forest, unsupervised-learning

I just found a an algorithm (in scikit-learn) that performs Random Trees Embedding. I see that its quite powerful but I dont really understand how it works. Is there any intuitive explanation + some links to the theory so I could follow?